# apache not running php after installing PHP gd library

Tags: php, apache, amazon-linux

I have installed LAMP on my EC2 instance which is running on AMAZON linux. Here are the packages installed

```
Installed Packages
httpd24.x86_64                          2.4.25-1.68.amzn1                    @amzn-updates
mysql56-server.x86_64                   5.6.35-1.23.amzn1                    @amzn-updates
php70.x86_64                            7.0.14-1.20.amzn1                    @amzn-updates
php70-mysqlnd.x86_64                    7.0.14-1.20.amzn1                    @amzn-updates
```

I have checked by running PHP file from /php.info.

But after installing php5-gd everything got broken. Apache starts serving test file and when running PHP file it is just giving me plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with PHP 7, you need to use gd package `php7.0-gd` rather than `php5-gd`. You can read about the php7.0-gd package here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-gd

You could also find the following page on gd and php version requirements for various versions useful http://php.net/manual/en/image.requirements.php

Comment: Thanks John, I removed the php5-gd and issue got fixed.